# How does dynamic memory allocation work?

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

Consider the following code:

```
int *p = malloc(4);
int *i = malloc(4);
```

Now, a chunk of memory (4 bytes in the above situation) has been allocated and the base address is stored in `p`.

While allocating the memory in the line `int *i = malloc(4)`.

**How does the compiler come to know that this chunk of memory is allocated?**

Why is it not allocating the same chunk of memory that has been allocated with `int *p = malloc(4)` ?

Comment: The compiler doesn't need to know. In fact it's possible to pass any pointer to `free`, even invalid ones. That leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) but the C compiler can not stop you from doing it.

Comment: that your job as C dev.

Comment: Your edit makes the question completely unclear.  The bolded sentence is saying two different things and makes no sense.

Comment: Even after your edit, it's not up to the compiler itself, but the implementation of the `malloc` function. It could be implemented by the compiler-writer, or it could just call some operating-system specific function for the allocation. The C language specification doesn't say how the standard library functions (like `malloc`) should be implemented, only how they should behave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use routines like `malloc` in your code and and compile and link your code into an executable program, a library of software routines is linked into your code too. The routines in that library have software for requesting memory from the operating system, for dividing that memory into parts and giving it out when requested with `malloc`, and for keeping track of what has been given out and what has been released with `free`.

So, whenever you compile a very small program, you get along with it a large library of additional software that people have worked on for many years.

Comment: Ok ...You say that kernel keeps track of all the memory that is given to malloc..?????

Comment: @Comp_sci_student: Implementations of C come with a library of software commonly called the standard C library. This library becomes a part of your program. It runs in the same process, using the same memory, just like subroutines you could have written yourself. The software in that library keeps track of memory for `malloc` and `free`. That software does request memory from the operating system, which is outside your process. The operating system has its own software to keep track of memory it has given to processes.

Comment: @Comp_sci_student: The word “kernel” is a bit vague. Today’s operating systems are huge and have many layers and subsystems. A part called the kernel might be a small or large part of that, and memory management is typically a part of it to some extent.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is not responsible for knowing who has what piece of memory and not accidentally trampling over previous allocated memory. This is a the job of the operating system. The compiler generates assembly code where in the assembly code makes the appropriate system calls to get a pointer to a piece of dynamic memory from the OS. To demonstrate, here's a silly example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int* ptr = malloc(4);
    free(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Now when that program is compiled and `main` is disassembled, the assembly code looks something like:

```
   0x0000000100000f50 <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x0000000100000f51 <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000100000f54 <+4>:     sub    $0x10,%rsp
   0x0000000100000f58 <+8>:     mov    $0x4,%eax
   0x0000000100000f5d <+13>:    mov    %eax,%edi
   0x0000000100000f5f <+15>:    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x0000000100000f66 <+22>:    callq  0x100000f8a
   0x0000000100000f6b <+27>:    mov    %rax,-0x10(%rbp)
   0x0000000100000f6f <+31>:    mov    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000100000f73 <+35>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x0000000100000f76 <+38>:    callq  0x100000f84
   0x0000000100000f7b <+43>:    xor    %eax,%eax
   0x0000000100000f7d <+45>:    add    $0x10,%rsp
   0x0000000100000f81 <+49>:    pop    %rbp
   0x0000000100000f82 <+50>:    retq
```

Notice the `callq` line. The compiler is just responsible for calling the appropriate system calls to get dynamic memory.

Comment: Those are calls to library routines, not system calls. The library routines contain system calls, but they also contain considerable in-process software to manage memory. It would be inefficient to use a system call for every allocation. The library requests large amounts from the system and partitions it into pieces as needed.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Right, I should've specified those jump to those library functions contain the actual sys calls.